# How can I install jmeter 5.5 in ubuntu 22.04 LTS(GNOME 42.5, windowing system->wayland)

Tags: command-line, 22.04, apache2, flatpak, mozilla

I tried installing .zip binary of jmeter from it's official website, but kept showing error. It doesn't install successfully. After then, I tried installing it from flatpak, but couldn't find the bin folder containing certificate required to import in firefox. Can any one please help me?
This is the error I get when using 'jmeter' command for the one that I installed from official website. Also, I coudn't share the screenshot of that error here.This is what it says in error message:

jmeter.sh: 99: [: Illegal number:
./jmeter: 128: [: Illegalnumber:
./jmeter: 199: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: not found.

But I do have jdk installed, and I have been using java, eclipse, selenium and testng without any problems.

And, from the one that I installed from flatpak, the GUI runs smoothly but, I couldn't find "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA" certificate to import in mozilla anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the exact error message you're seeing (2) which version of Ubuntu 22.04 you're using (Server / Desktop)? With this, it will be easier to offer a solution 

Comment: Screenshot would make it easier to understand the error I got but I couldn't upload it here

Comment: Could you [edit] into your question the output in a terminal of `ls /usr/lib/jvm/*/bin/java` and of `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `echo $JRE_HOME`?  I think they may be pointing to an old uninstalled version of java.

Comment: The java version I have currently is java 1.19.0

Comment: Thank you! I figured out my mistake. But, the only one thing remaining is, there is no "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA" in bin directory for linux which I need to import in mozilla